# Transitions occur slowly while a d3.drag() is occuring

Tags: performance, d3.js, transition

While dragging an element (e1) using (d3.drag()) a separate element (e2) transitions very slowly based upon the drag rate of e1.

I'm new to d3 and some of the underlying workings an may simply be just taking the wrong approach.

I've seen information about problems trying to perform multiple transitions on the same element, but in this case these are completely different elements.

You can see the block at the URL below:
https://bl.ocks.org/aitee/1db30487d5cee6e752420fc5dc44c120/16fe33235a785c5c81932af4336d280ea0c15660

Just drag the vertical cursor past the 50 on the x-axis. You'll notice based upon the speed of the cursor dragging, the value box transition speed is affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a programming error caused by restarting the transition during the drag. The re-transition caused the transition to slow down (as I was using one of the slow start ease functions).

I fixed it by guarding against re-transitioning while already transitioning.